# Windows8 ListView LineHeight

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have added a ListView to a Metro Style Blank App.  Added to the ListView are 3 Strings.  I want to change the LineHeight , but cannot find a property.  Below is my xaml code.

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundBrush}">
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="277.167" Margin="235.51,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <ListView.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform SkewX="-0.338" TranslateX="-0.327"/>
        </ListView.RenderTransform>
        <x:String>test 1</x:String>
        <x:String>Test2</x:String>
        <x:String>Test3</x:String>
   </ListView>
</Grid>
```

How do I decrease, increase the line height of the strings in the ListView box?  I want to decrease the space between the lines.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to achieve by changing the line-height? Make it look bigger? (use font size instead). Make it have more space around it? (use paddings / margin on the list view item). In any case, you may have to provide a DataTemplate to change the style of each item (string).

Answer (score 0):

Try editing a ItemContainerTemplate and then play with the properties available like margin and padding.
See my answer here :
[WPF ComboBox customization in windows8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706056/wpf-combobox-customization-in-windows8/12775497#12775497)

let me know in case you need any help.